# WPF Trigger to change Cursor

Tags: wpf, triggers, mouse-cursor

I need to change the cursor of a TreeViewItem in a trigger.  This code works for all other properties but not Cursor:

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <MultiTrigger>
     <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="QuickPhrases:TreeViewChecker.IsMouseDirectlyOverItem"    
                   Value="True">
        </Condition>
        <Condition Property="CanSelect" Value="True"></Condition>
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
      <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
  </MultiTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

What gives, and also, how do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it correctly, it should just work. In fact I'm unable to reproduce your issue via the following steps:

- Created a new project via VS 2008 C# WPF application wizard.

  - resulting in App.xaml and Window1.xaml
- Added a standard TreeView from the toolbox to Window1.
- Added 2 TreeViewItems '1' and '2'.
- Added a Style with `TargetType="TreeViewItem"`.
- Pasted your snippet as is, but modified the conditions to something local of course.

Well, this is just working fine, i.e. once hovering over a TreeViewItem the cursor gets triggered to whatever value I chose in the trigger, be it 'Hand' or 'Wait' or else.

One important detail though: the cursor only appears while hovering directly over the header, i.e. **not** the entire row (this is consistent with WPF TreeViewItem row behavior though, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664632/highlight-whole-treeviewitem-line-in-wpf) for a related example regarding row highlighting). Especially the cursor does **not** appear when the TeeViewItem header is empty! Have you supplied any data for the headers yet?

Otherwise their must be something weird going on behind the scenes in your project/environment? Have you tried a simple repro case like this already?