# WPF TreeView Highlight Row On Hover

Tags: wpf, treeview, styles, hover, highlight

Currently, hovering over a header in the TreeView will highlight the header. I would like hovering over any part of the row in the TreeView to highlight the entire row (much like windows explorer does). Could someone provide an example of how to do that?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight whole TreeViewItem line in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664632/highlight-whole-treeviewitem-line-in-wpf)

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the `ControlTemplate` for the `TreeViewItem` to actually be the entire width of the control.

There is a discussion about this issue, along with a solution, here:

http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2009/01/horizontal-stretch-on-treeviewitems.html

There's another lengthy answer here, without the discussion:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b04f73e2-0b10-4d97-a6da-64df2e30c21d/

So I meant those examples to be guides. If you take exactly the same code as is in the second link above (from MSDN forums) and just add this:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
</Trigger>
```

to the `ControlTemplate` you'll see that you get the highlight color on mouseover. Obviously you'll need to tweak the color and whatnot, but that's what you'll need to do - modify the `ControlTemplate` of the `TreeViewItem` so that it takes up the entire width and add a `Trigger` for `IsMouseOver`.

Comment: That example just makes the header bigger and it only highlights the header on selection. I want a highlight of the entire row (including the expand button and blank space before) and I want the highlight to happen on hover not on select.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide more information. Its not exactly what you're asking for (you'll need to tweak it), but it should get you going.

Comment: The lee campbell link and all the discussion is only to stretch the highlight all the way to the right, it does not stretch left.