Set style of child of TreeViewItem on mouse hover
I have a tree view:
<Window.Resources>
    <VisualBrush x:Key="HighlightBrush">LightBlue</VisualBrush>
    <Style x:Key="RectangleStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<TreeView Grid.Column ="0" Name="MyTreeView">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    <!-- Set property "Visibility" of child Rectangle "Hb" to "visible -->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <d:TreeView.ItemsSource >
        <x:Array Type="system:String">
            <system:String>First element</system:String>
            <system:String>Second element</system:String>
        </x:Array>
    </d:TreeView.ItemsSource>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" d:Text="{Binding .}" />
                <Rectangle x:Name="Hb" Width="100000" Margin="-10000,0,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="-1" Visibility="Hidden" Style="{DynamicResource  RectangleStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

I figured out how to set the background of the TreeViewItem on mouse hover.
How can I set the visibility of Rectangle Hb which is a child of the TreeViewItem to visible on mouse hover of the TreeViewItem?
Note: The idea for this method of highlighting the current item comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1627451/2484903.

You may add a DataTrigger on the IsMouseOver property of the TreeViewItem to the Rectangle Style. The Fill Brush should also be a SolidColorBrush:
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightBrush">LightBlue</SolidColorBrush>
    <Style x:Key="RectangleStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}"
                Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

Alternatively, you could bind the Rectangle's Visibility to the IsMouseOver property like this:
<Rectangle x:Name="Hb" ...
    Visibility="{Binding IsMouseOver,
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem},
                 Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

with a BooleanToVisibilityConverter resource e.g. in Window.Resources:
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightBrush">LightBlue</SolidColorBrush>
    <Style x:Key="RectangleStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


Awesome, works great! But this "Hb" hack has some downsides: Hover only works on top of text, not the whole row. Also it interferes with clicking the expand triangle. So good answer, bad question. Besides for anyone not needing a tree: I just noticed that a simple ListBox supports line highlighting out-of-the-box.

BooleanToVisibilityConverter sets Collapsed, not Hidden, so that no mouse input is recognized on the row. Use DataTrigger instead of Binding. Or write your own Converter that sets Hidden instead of Collapsed.
